# jquery appendTo() issue

Tags: jquery, appendto

I'm trying to use jQuery's appendTo function to add data to some html that I load from another file.
Why won't this work:

```
$('#pop-up').load('html_elements/news.html #newsItem', function() {
     $(newsItems[$(event.target).attr('href')].title).appendTo($(this).find('.title'));
     gameUi.showPopUp();
     gameUi.setUpPopUp();
} );
```

and by "this" I mean this:

```
$(newsItems[$(event.target).attr('href')].title).appendTo($(this).find('.title'));
```

all of the individual parts work... newsItems[...] returns a string that is the title. and $(this).find('.title')) returns the element I'm trying to target, but when I test it nothing is appended to the h2 tag.

I'm by no means a javascript / jquery pro so any ideas are welcome.
Thanks!

Comment: where is `event` coming from?

Comment: it's coming the function that this code is set into.  You click an anchor and and the click event fires and a bunch of stuff happens, including what's above, sorry it wasn't clear.

Answer (score 2):

I think what you're after here is [`.append()`](http://api.jquery.com/append/) instead of [`.appendTo()`](http://api.jquery.com/appendTo/), like this:

```
$(this).find('.title').append(newsItems[$(event.target).attr('href')].title);
```

If you're appending content like a string use `.append()`, otherwise it's trying to use your `newsItems[x].title` as a selector, and not finding any elements with it to append.

Comment: yep, you beat me to answering my own question.

Answer (score 0):

I've found that just using reqular append does the trick... I have to read up on some documentation I guess.

```
$(this).find('.title').append(newsItems[$(event.target).attr('href')].title);
```